# how to run android application on intex xloud x1 could not find its drivers

Tags: android

I want to run my own android application and sample application on my android intex x1 phone android version 2.3 a low budget phone. I connect my phone with laptop it said driver failed may be my mobile drivers.
But I have other drivers like tethering and storage(because my phone is connected).
can any one tell me what drivers i need. i don't know what are OEM drivers 0r ADB drivers.
i am finding the solution from last two days. but could not downloaded\find any working drivers. I am using window 7 and on eclipse AVD if working normally. I getting solutions like how to root your mobile etc. 
I want to run application on my android phone. Please direct me some steps. I think their are no drivers available.
Is their any other solution like universal ADB drivers or like that.

Is http://pdanet.co/bin/PdaNetA4150.exe a solution in my case?

Comment: You can use [Mobogenie](http://www.mobogenie.com/en-us/download.html) software to connect any device and on developer mode and USB debugging of mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use universal drivers that connect to any device. download your drivers from intexmobile.in.
or use software like mobogenie or pdanet+.